# Will make operations in-place increase the performance of Metal shaders?

Tags: metal

In my app, I use custom metal shaders to perform operations on large arrays. Before I rewrite all my shaders, I'd like to ask for some opinions on how to improve the overall performance.

Consider this example shader:

```
kernel void makeAverage(device float *stackBuffer [[ buffer(0) ]],
                        device float *newBuffer [[ buffer(1) ]],
                        device float *destinationBuffer [[ buffer(2)]],
                        device float &count [[buffer (3) ]],
                               uint gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
    


          destinationBuffer[gid] = (stackBuffer[gid] + newBuffer[gid])*count;
    
}
```

I take two input buffers (stackBuffer and newBuffer) and I populate the destinationBuffer with the results of some calculations. My question is:

1. what if instead of having a destination buffer, I write directly on the stackBuffer:

   stackBuffer[gid] = (stackBuffer[gid] + newBuffer[gid])*count;

Will this increase performance, besides the advantage of saving up memory?

Comment: The right answer for any performance question is to "measure it". It should be pretty simple to take an instruments trace, or a gputrace and see how fast each version goes. In this case though, I'm not sure how you expect more performance by just changing the destination buffer to a differently named destination buffer. It still has to write out anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I measured it and it didn't make much difference as you correctly pointed out.

Comment: Yeah, any calculation would happen in GPU registers, which means GPU would have to load it to memory, make all the calculations and put it back into memory. There might be a slight difference depending on caching patters, since you might end up writing and reading from same cache lines, but yeah. There's no way to do calculations in place in memory.